# How to POST Oauth2PermissionGrants in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are looking to automatize admin consent for Azure Enterprise Applications through Microsoft graph, more specifically `/beta/oauth2permissiongrants/

We have already successfully deployed an app that can do this, [but now it fails](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/breaking-changes-application-and-serviceprincipal-api-updates-in-microsoft-graph-beta/).

The error message is related to property `expiryTime` which has been recently deprecated. We have tried to change our `POST` to leave that property out, but it still fails. And if we leave it in, it also fails. And it worked just fine before.

```
{
 "clientId":"6b765713-9aac-4bf3-a5e9-4c11228e2e49",
 "consentType":"AllPrincipals",
 "resourceId":"ac07f639-74ff-459e-b335-2fcc434dbd76",
 "scope":"User.Read openid",
}
```

Return is

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Missing property: expiryTime",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d61927fe-4ab9-40a9-9b7e-ff33c138bb93",
            "date": "2019-09-16T12:18:06"
        }
    }
}
```

The `expiryTime` property shouldn't be relevant anymore, yet no matter what we do we get an error message that says it is missing.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: What do you get if you include `expiryTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't add expiryTime property in the request body, I will get the error the same as yours.

[image]

But after adding it to the request body, I can post successfully.

[image]

By the way, beta version api is not recommended to use.

> APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.
>   Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Comment: Hi. The problem seemed to disappear by itself. I realize this is a beta, and we are not currently depending on this in our production environment. We are just exploring options to simplify admin consent grants, and the beta API seems very promising.

Comment: @MariusØstby Glad to hear that.